# Get view in GridView by text

Tags: android, gridview

I have a simple question, which you can see in the title. Is there an opportunity to find element in gridview knowing text of this view?

Comment: What are you trying to get? The View that is currently displayed? Or the object that is displayed?

Comment: View that has text, that I know. For example, I have a calendar, and I know date, and I need to get view for this date

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the View Class called:

```
public void findViewsWithText (ArrayList<View> outViews, CharSequence searched, int flags)
```

[See Docs Here...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewsWithText%28java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29)

this will do exactly what you want, however, it will not be as "tight" as you would like because there might be several views with the same text this is why it returns an ArrayList of views that match the required text.

I suggest using

```
public final View findViewWithTag (Object tag)
```

[See Docs Here...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

And use an Int as the tag that represents the day number.